# Stop Google Play Music service automatically pops up. After HeadPhone is connected

Tags: android, google-play

In my app I have this kind of problem.
When I am plugging in my headphones (custom medical headPhone) the Google Play Music is starting automatically. I don't need it that way!

So I tried to stop that service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
stopService(intent);
```

But there is no result.

I don't want Google Play Music to start automatically.
So how can I avoid this kind of situation programmatically ?